# HTML5: contenteditable div with blocked height and new div creation when text reaches the bottom

Tags: html, contenteditable, fixed, dimensions

I'm wondering how to avoid that a DIV with fixed dimensions on width and high and allowed contenteditable feature does not increase its high when the user, typing characters inside, exceed the DIV high. In fact, even trying to define a fixed high I notice that filling the entire DIV space with words and going simply beyond the browser automatically increases the DIV high. On the contrary I need a blocked DIV high, no scroll bar appearing, and eventually I would like that a new DIV would be created on the high limit reached event reacehd where the user characters flow will be put and displayed. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: For example you can try this code: as you can see enabling contenteditable feature, if you write ong text the div box will be expaded atomatically by the browser:

Comment: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function toggleEdit() {
    var newState = !editableText.isContentEditable
    editableText.contentEditable = newState
    editableText.className = (newState) ? "editing" : "normal"
    editBtn.innerText = (newState) ? "Disable Editing" : "Enable Editing"
}
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>
<H1>Editing Contents</H1>
<HR>
<P>Turn on editing to modify the following text:</P>

<DIV ID="editableText" style="high:100px; width:100px; text-align:justify">Edit this text on the fly....</DIV>
<P><BUTTON ID="editBtn" onClick="toggleEdit()" onFocus="this.blur()">
Enable Editing
</BUTTON>

Answer (score 2):

The div can keep its height as defined if you set the css correctly:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black; height:100px; overflow:hidden" contentEditable="true">
line 1 type here<br>
   line 2<br>
   line 3<br>
   line 4<br>
   line 5<br>
   line 6<br>
</div>
```

With regards to creating a new div when the contents is higher than the allowed height, you'll have to create some function that checks those values and acts accordingly.

Comment: are these values available from JavaScript as element/environment variable? I mean, I can realize a function that on ever div content modification is called, but then how can I understand if any element inside the dive (text, added image, table, ...) exceed the 100th pixel?

Comment: Using any javascript library you should be able to easily get the dimensions of any object. But if don't know how to get that, I guess that you'll face big problems when you try to implement the rest of features for an editor.

Comment: Yes, but, in this specific case, since I don't need to know the height of the DIV element because I fixed it and it shouldn't change (so in other words it should be intrinsecally known and not changing) I wonder if the same JavaScript libraries could return to me the height reached by the content **inside** the DIV element.

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS Properties

```
 white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
```